# execute function in navicat function editor gives different result than from console mysql

Tags: mysql, function, navicat

I have function to calculate final result from another table calculation, I try to execute function from navicat editor, it gives correct result. But when I using console to execute these function doesn't gives the correct result, just null.

the function name is saldoakun and the parameter is '111101'

Thanks for your help.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

for long time, try and try.. the answer is.

Some variable that I set it to local variable (with @variablename), cannot identify from console. Yes, when I change the variable to public, problem solved.